# How do I give Credentials programmatically using WSDL Importer

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

I am building an app the uses Soap to access data. I used the WSDL Importer. Works Great but I can not find the place to put in credentials. When run windows asks for credentials. I want to enter the username and password programmatically.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Typically you will be setting `HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.UserName := Username;` and
`HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.Password := Password;`